# Concating a string, query and sequence number in a trigger

Tags: oracle11g, triggers, oracle-sqldeveloper

Here is my trigger called which increments the sequence number

`create sequence application_id_seq start with 100 increment by 1;`

```
create or replace trigger application_id_trig
before insert on applicant
for each row
begin
:new.application_id := 'ABC'|| to_char(application_id_seq.nextval);
end application_id_trig;
```

This outputs me to
how can I change it so that I get a following output.

ABC+sysdate(year)+seq_no.

ex:**ABC2015101**

Comment: You forgot to attach output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that what you want?

```
create or replace trigger application_id_trig
before insert on applicant
for each row
begin
:new.application_id := 'ABC'||to_char(sysdate,'YYYY') || to_char(application_id_seq.nextval);
end application_id_trig;
```